# webpack HtmlWebpackPlugin wont create link css tag

Tags: css, webpack, sass

Im experiencing a problem with webpack.

The plugin HtmlWebpackPlugin is not creating the tag  And I cant figure it out why. Only the JS tag is included.

**as plugins I have**

```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    inject: false,
    // hash: true,
    template: __dirname + '/../src/app/Views/layouts/layout-template.phtml',
    filename: __dirname + '/../src/app/Views/layouts/layout.phtml',
  }),
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'css/[name].css'
  })
```

**as rules:**

```
  {
    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      },
      'css-loader',
      'postcss-loader',
      'sass-loader',
    ],
  },
```

I would appreciate help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling to HTMLWebpackPlugin not to inject them by `inject: false`.
Just remove `inject: false` attribute.

Comment: But that inject:false is to prevent the default injection. If i take that option of i get two js injections, the default and the one in the template. But either ways i can't make the link tag appear.

Comment: This don't return any results.
<% for (let css in htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css) { %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.files.css[css] %>">
    <% } %>

Comment: Ha, so can you share your `layout-template.phtml`?

Comment: Thank you brother, but i figured it out. Posted ir above. Since im not used to webpack i guess it's a newbie mistake. Maybe will help others. Cheers!

Comment: This is one solution, other solution would to import the styles file from within index.js

`import './scss/styles.css';`

Answer (score 1):

I just figure it out. I needed to include the scss also as an entry point.

```
entry: {
      main: [
        './src/private/index.js',
        './src/private/scss/style.scss'
      ],
},
```

I'm kinda new to webpack, and the documentation or examples, or are outdated or confusing.